# Is there a way to download docker hub images whitout "docker pull" for a machine with out Internet access?

Tags: docker, docker-registry, dockerhub

I want to download some images for a computer that has not internet.

My computer that have internet has NO DOCKER installed (old kernel) so it is not possible to use docker command to pull, save and export it to the other machine.

I'm looking for a way to download a docker image (like via wget, ...) and use it on my computer without Internet.

Comment: [Pulling docker images](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22381442/pulling-docker-images) is a little dated, but there might be some ideas there.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to download docker images without using pull command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37905763/how-to-download-docker-images-without-using-pull-command)

Comment: The Moby contrib script worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49001969/908336

Answer (score 7):

Yes that's possible. Docker has the features [save](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/save/) and [load](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/load/).

Run this command on your machine with the image you want to copy to the other computer:

```
docker save myimage > myimage.tar
```

To load the image again run:

```
docker load < myimage.tar
```

Comment: I can't install docker on my computer with internet. My kernel is too old.

Comment: If your kernel is too old you can't use docker. Upgrade your kernel first.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have access to a machine supporting docker in any way what you can do is create a repository on quay.io with a dockerfile like

```
FROM myimage
...
```

quay actually allows to download images from the web panel whereas docker hub/store does not afaik.