# Download docker image from artifactory using curl or wget..?

Tags: unix, docker, curl, wget

Do we have any option/way to download a docker image using wget or curl.
My docker image is present in Jfrog artifactory.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, any curl command to an Artifactory repo would need the API key of your account. See "[How to use docker registry API with Artifactory Docker Repository when not using docker client?](https://jfrog.com/knowledge-base/how-to-use-docker-registry-api-with-artifactory-docker-repository-when-not-using-docker-client/)"

> you can use the following header: "X-JFrog-Art-Api" and pass the API key of the user to authenticate. The API key of the user can be retrieved from the "User Profile" page in Artifactory. Artifactory REST API supports three forms of authentication and you can use any one of them with the docker repository

Second, downloading an image is not trivial (as you need to get all the layers).
You might have some chance adapting the moby contrib script [`download-frozen-image-v2.sh`](https://github.com/moby/moby/blob/master/contrib/download-frozen-image-v2.sh)

Or try [`docker-registry-debug`](https://github.com/samalba/docker-registry-debug) which will  print a curl command for fetching the layer, as [explained here](https://serverfault.com/a/823571/783).

Answer (score 0):

I found this answer while looking to do the same thing with gitlab.  I modified the suggested moby contrib script to do the same thing for a gitlab instance.

1. Download [download-gitlab-frozen-docker-image.sh](https://gitlab.com/-/snippets/2483762/raw/main/download-gitlab-frozen-docker-image.sh?inline=false)
2. Mark it executable (`chmod +x download-gitlab-frozen-docker-image.sh`)
3. Run the script:

   ```
   ./download-gitlab-frozen-docker-image.sh <FOLDER_NAME> <DOCKER_URL>
   ```

   where `FOLDER_NAME` is the folder to store the frozen docker image and `DOCKER_URL` is the url straight out of the gitlab container registry.
4. Import the frozen folder into docker (at your convenience/any future date):

   ```
   tar -cC '<FOLDER_NAME>' . | docker load
   ```