# Downloading Docker Images through shell script

Tags: shell, docker, download

I want to write a shell script which can automatically download docker images from hub.docker website. Up til now I only found docker pull command to get the image from docker hub. But I want to know is it possible to manually download Image from docker hub without using command and if possible how can I write shell script for this.

I have tried using 'wget' command but the script is not giving any output.

Comment: Check question is already posted: https://stackoverflow.com/q/49001798/2987755

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Download docker image from artifactory using curl or wget..?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49001798/download-docker-image-from-artifactory-using-curl-or-wget)

Comment: Also: https://devops.stackexchange.com/q/2731